# ViewController not changing after first time use

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

Hi I want to show a view controller only at the first use (i.e: the first time someone starts the app up and never again).

I think I have the right code but for some reason it's just not working. Does anyone know why?

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.init()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "isFirstTime")
        userDefaults.set("RealmNotChosenOrSuggested", forKey: "RegionPreference")
        userDefaults.set([], forKey: "PreferredRealms")

        // Not using Storyboard instantiation code
        window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds) //canvas
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        if (userDefaults.bool(forKey: "isFirstTime")){
            userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "isFirstTime")
            window?.rootViewController = StartupViewController()
        } else{
            window?.rootViewController = DashboardViewController()
        }
        return true
    }
```

StartupViewController.swift

```
class StartupViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
```

DashboardViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every time app opens this runs you overwrite the key `isFirstTime` in the first line

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  //  userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "isFirstTime") // firs line comment it


if !(userDefaults.bool(forKey: "isFirstTime")){
    userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "isFirstTime")
    userDefaults.set("RealmNotChosenOrSuggested", forKey: "RegionPreference")
    userDefaults.set([], forKey: "PreferredRealms")
    window?.rootViewController = StartupViewController()
} else{
    window?.rootViewController = DashboardViewController()
}
```

Comment: default value for any bool is false when you read a key from defaults